# Web-scraping HTML, javascript is not being executed, therefore missing pieces of HTML. How do I execute all script tags to edit the DOM?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, iframe

I am using Selenium to try and get the HTML doc nested in all iframe tags. I am able to get the HTML within the iframe but there are  tags that I believe are not being executed, leaving me without all the source code I want. Is there a way to get the HTML execute the javascript and then work with the new HTML after the javascript has run?

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/G/chromedriver.exe')

browser.get("http://www.reddit.com")

time.sleep(1)

innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")

time.sleep(1)

iframes = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")

time.sleep(1)

for iframe in iframes:

    browser.switch_to_default_content()
    browser.switch_to_frame(iframe)

    source = browser.page_source    

    time.sleep(1)

    print(source)
```

Comment: What tags do you "believe" are not being "executed," and why do you believe this?

Comment: Executing javascript in an HTML file can add to the DOM. When I retrieve the inner HTML of the iframe and print it out, I only get one large script tag that has not been executed. I "believe" they are not being "executed" because if you look at the page source with chrome inspector there is more HTML that I am not seeing from my print statement.

Comment: nothing beats tampermonkey for scraping, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your Question correctly you are trying to get the **`innerHTML`** nested within all **`<iframe>`** tags, so first we need to **`switch_to_frame`** first and **`Selenium`** can only **`switch_to_frame`** if the frame is visible. To achieve that you can use the following code block :

```
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
for iframe in iframes:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("iframe"))
    print(driver.page_source)
    driver.switch_to_default_content()
```